# How to operate on a directory with different owner from a script?

Tags: permissions, logs, chown, elasticsearch, chgrp

Few days ago i have installed elasticsearch,

For diagnosing some problems on my elasticsearch setup, i have checked the logs files located in `/var/log/elasticsearch` and tailed them but apparently the directory's owner is `elasticsearch` and the group is `elasticsearch`, therefore i have resolved it by switching to root and apply the tail (not an elegant way).

Now I would like to write a simple script to tail those files (I'm using tmux), Does anybody has a suggestion how to overcome the the privileges issue while using a script? I prefer keeping the ownership to `elasticsearch` user.

Comment: Will the script be run by root?

Comment: I prefer not, although I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering 'Stuart' is the user running your script, you can :

- make Stuart a member of the `elasticsearch` group (provided group members can actually access these log files)
- OR make the directory + logs readable by Stuart. This implies :

  - setting the execution bit on `/var/log/elasticsearch` so that Stuart can enter it
  - setting the read bit on `/var/log/elasticsearch/whatever.log` so that Stuart can actually read it
- OR define `sudo` privileges (but this sounds overkill)